# Access database to SQL, error on Data Type 130 using SSMS Importation tool

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, import, ssms

I created a new Database and used the SSMS importation tool to import my Access Database to it. When I select all the databases the SSMS throws me this error:

```
Column 'FEC': The source data type '130' was not found in the data type mapping file
```

In Access the type of this column is **Short Text** of **5 characters**.

It warns me the same error on 5 tables.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: this might answer your problem

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062100/convert-access-database-to-sql-microsoft-dts-data-type-130-not-in-mapping-fi